# How to insert a record into multiple tables using a trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two Tables.

I want to insert the same record on both tables at the same time.
I.e., while I insert a record for the first table, this same record also is inserted in the second table using a trigger.

Do you have any experience/advice in this process ?

Comment: How are you inserting records into the original table to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

if you're using stored procedures you can easily manage this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Insert
@Value varchar(10)
AS
insert into table1 (...,...) values (@value,...)
insert into table2 (...,...) values (@value,...)
```

Comment: That is the easy way to handle it, in one SP, much more readable and easy to debug.  Triggers can be trickey as once setup you can forget they are there and not understand why data is changing.

Comment: I don;t know what your environment is but if you're using C# in VS take a look at this tutorial. It's about using ADO.Net and stored procedures in C#.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Erik's method over a trigger.  Triggers tend to cause performance issues, and a lot of times, you forget that the trigger exists, and get unexpected behavior.  If you do want to use a trigger however, it will work.  here is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgTest ON Test
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT Test2
     (Id, value)
SELECT Id, Value 
FROM Inserted
```

Answer (score 0):

Can Use Cursor Concept!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_order
BEFORE INSERT
ON ord
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.payment_type = 'CREDIT')
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_check_customer IS
   SELECT 'x'
   FROM   customer
   WHERE  customer_id = :NEW.customer_id
   AND    credit_rating = 'POOR';
lv_temp_txt          VARCHAR2(1);
lv_poor_credit_excep EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
OPEN cur_check_customer;
FETCH cur_check_customer INTO lv_temp_txt;
IF (cur_check_customer%FOUND) THEN
   CLOSE cur_check_customer;
   RAISE lv_poor_credit_excep;
ELSE
   CLOSE cur_check_customer;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN lv_poor_credit_excep THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20111, 'Cannot process CREDIT ' ||
      'order for a customer with a POOR credit rating.');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20122, 'Unhandled error occurred in' ||
      ' BI_ORDER trigger for order#:' || TO_CHAR(:NEW.ORDER_ID));
END bi_order;
```